# I use Azure Search which in turn uses Lucene. Is there a way I can search this query: colo?r which will result to get "color" and "colour" values?

Tags: azure, lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I have already tried doing like this:

colo?r - not working
colo?r - based on Azure Search documentation
/colo?r/ - not working

Is there someone who knows how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex to make the "u" optional: `/colou?r/`

In your example `colo?r` doesn't work because "?" outside of a regex means that any character should match but the character is not optional (so "color" won't match in that case). The `/colo?r/` regular expression makes the second "o" optional by using "?" but still doesn't allow for the extra "u", so it would match "colr" and "color", but not "colour".

Answer (score 0):

Testing the following works:

```
/.*colo*.r/
```